# Faster way to get CLR trigger's parent table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have a CLR trigger that is used to track changes in tables. The first step in the trigger is to get the table name associated with the trigger, so I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid and resource_type = 'OBJECT'
```

This works fine, however it takes ~40ms to complete and this is making the audit trigger really slow when 1000s of records and being updated.

Is there a faster way to get the table name?

Alternatively, would it be possible to pass the table name as parameter to the CLR trigger?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built in change tracking features?

Comment: Built-in tracking uses an audit table per table. Also, the database already has an audit table that goes back 10years and the same table needs to be used.